# Do maximally almost periodic groups embed homeomorphically into their Bohr compactifications?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, topological-groups, unitary-representations, compactifications, almost-periodic-function

If $G$ is a Hausdorff topological group and $bG$ is its Bohr compactification, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_compactification) that $G$ is called *maximally almost periodic* (MAP) if and only if the natural map $i : G \to bG$ is injective. Equivalently, MAP groups are those groups the points of which are separated by the finite-dimensional unitary representations. My question is:

> if $G$ is MAP, is $i$ a homeomorphism onto $i(G)$, or is it only injective?

(I would like to know if topological properties and regular measures on $i(G)$ can be pulled back on $G$.)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: Indeed, your answer there also answers my question, but before closing it myself let me also add you: does $i$ at least take Borel subsets to Borel subsets? I could have this if I imposed that $G$ and $bG$ were standard Borel spaces, but I was hoping that the topological group structure and compactness of $bG$ could make this assumption redundant.